# web-sql, javascript, show all tables of database

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I need to show on an Webpage all my Tables in my WebSQL-DB.
But I start first with JavaScript and WebSQL some Days before.

```
Database = DATABASE
Tables inside = Table1, Table2, Table3
```

This is my code:

```
<script>
    var db = openDatabase('DATABASE', '1.0', 'myDB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(
        function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE type = 'table'"), [],
            function(tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                var i;
                for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
                    alert(results.rows.item(i));
                }  
            }
        }
    );

</script>
```

The output must be not an alert. I am open to other ideas.

The Debugging-Tool of Google-Chrome shows no errors.

Comment: Are you getting the correct output in the alert box? If so, you could just use `document.write(results.rows.item(i  + "\n"));` instead of the alert.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for feedback. Sorry, no output. This is the my main problem! I don't understand why. I think, the SELECT ist not correct written, but i don't now what i must do :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Complete working code for your problem. The code creates a DB, 2 tables then inserts some data into it. Later we extract all the tables from the DB, then iterate the rows in the DB table. We output the results as html tables.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpNaor) for the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    table,tr,th,td{
      border-collapse:collapse;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
     var db;

    function runExample() {
      createDbAndTables();
      getAllTablesFromDB(getResultSetFromTable);
    }

    function createDbAndTables(callback) {
      db = openDatabase('mydb1', '1.0', 'my first database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl1 (id INTERGER UNIQUE, name TEXT)');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl2 (id INTERGER UNIQUE, name TEXT)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl1 (id,name) VALUES (1,"someone1")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl1 (id,name) VALUES (2,"someone2")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,name) VALUES (3,"someone3")');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,name) VALUES (4,"someone4")');
      });
    }

    function getAllTablesFromDB(callback) {
      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"', [], function(tx, results) {
          callback(results, processResultSet);
        });
      });
    }

    function getResultSetFromTable(results, callback) {
      var length = results.rows.length;
      var j = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
          var k=0,tblname=results.rows[j++].tbl_name;
          tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM ' + tblname , [], function(tx, results) {
            callback(tblname,results);
          });
        });
      }

    }

    function processResultSet(tblname,results) {
      console.log('----------------------'+tblname)
      var len = results.rows.length;
      var tbl = document.createElement('table');
      var trTblName = document.createElement('tr');
      var thTblName = document.createElement('th');
      thTblName.innerHTML = tblname;
      trTblName.colSpan = 2;
      trTblName.appendChild(thTblName);
      tbl.appendChild(trTblName);

      var trHeader = document.createElement('tr');
      var th1 = document.createElement('th');
      th1.innerHTML = 'id';
      var th2 = document.createElement('th');
      th2.innerHTML = 'name';
      trHeader.appendChild(th1);
      trHeader.appendChild(th2);
      tbl.appendChild(trHeader);

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML = results.rows[i].id;
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.innerHTML = results.rows[i].name;
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tbl.appendChild(tr);
      }
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      body.appendChild(tbl);
      body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="runExample()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, nice example. But it shows me the info from one table = foo. 
Not the info from a DB. 
The main problem is, that i want to see all my tables from the database.
I run your example and the page shows me => [object Object]
Importland for me, thanks for that, was the info about  "function processResultSet" and the "callback(result)".
The Debugging-Tool of Google-Chrome shows no errors in my Code, but there is no output :(
Why?

Comment: To get a list of all tables from the database, use the following sql 

SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"  

From this result set you can iterate over the tables and use the initial code to get the resultset from each table. I am short of time now, but will reply with full blown example later.

Comment: hi, nice one. i will check it, will give a feedback little bit later! Thanks :)

Comment: OK; woooow, nice code and it works, but the Script, i only changed the DB name to my name = DATABASE, prints out the following: 
1 undefined
1 someone1
2 someone2
3 someone3
4 someone4
Uh, where are the info of my tables in the same DB?
What must i change to see my tables in the DB = DATABASE?
Changing word "mydb1" to "DATABASE" not work. 
Now i have 2 more tables in my DB, but showing is only that what i wrote upside.
Some idea?
PS: Sorry for my bad english :(

Comment: and one more :)
after deleting my DATABASE and use your script, it runs cool and perfekt, but i saw only the inserts of the table. i want to see how many tables in the DATABASE and there NAMES. tbl_name give me a feedback of = column-name and not of table-name!!!!
Example: My Table-Name = "test" and inside we have the columns = "id" and "name". id = 1 and name = test123 Then on the page comes an outpoint of = 1test123
I need there the name of the DATABASE - TABLE like table1, table2, table3
I think we use the wrong Select Option?

Comment: @Gen-One I believe you have all the code necessary to see what you want. Just modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: as a beginner, it is not possible for me.
=> *** tx.executeSql('SELECT tbl_name from sqlite_master WHERE type = "table"', *** - not working and do not fix my problem. i want to see the table names als outprint, not the inserts of the tables and the table-header.
hope other people can help a little bit to bring me back to the line :)

Comment: @Gen-One I have updated the answer and also a new codepen is provided to see it in action. I have basically given you entire working code. I advice you to go through the code line by line to really understand how the control flows around in the code. I hope you accept this solution as answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, Sorry! My mistake. As a Newbie it was a litte bit hard for me. Now i understand and it works. *yeaaaa* Biggest respect to people like you! Your help was so important for me! Best wishes and a good time. CU

Comment: @Gen-One, glad that you have gone through the code and understood the concept. For the benefit of everyone, can accept the solution as answer