# websql add button to insert new values in table

Tags: javascript, web-sql

I am a newbie and i need help, it is to complex for me.
Sorry for my bad englisch.

I have this cool Code from @rushi and now i need a button to insert and to update a change and send it back into the table.

On the page it looks nice, there is a button on the end of the table-view and the input type = text has the right value from the table connect (see picture)!

[image: picture]

The original code block from rushi u find here -> [web-sql, javascript, show all tables of database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620761/web-sql-javascript-show-all-tables-of-database)

This is the code in the moment.
Can u help me to find the solution for the "update-button"?

```js
 function processResultSet(tblname,results) {
      console.log('----------------------'+tblname)
      var len = results.rows.length;
      var tbl = document.createElement('table');
      var trTblName = document.createElement('tr');
      var thTblName = document.createElement('th');
      thTblName.innerHTML = tblname;
      trTblName.colSpan = 2;
      trTblName.appendChild(thTblName);
      tbl.appendChild(trTblName);
        
     //create Table-Head

      var trHeader = document.createElement('tr');
      var th1 = document.createElement('th');
      th1.innerHTML = '<font color=orange> ID STEMPEL</font>';
      var th2 = document.createElement('th');
      th2.innerHTML = '<font color=red> HERSTELLER </font>';
      var th3 = document.createElement('th');
      th3.innerHTML = '<font color=green> STÜCKZAHL </font>';
    var th4 = document.createElement('th');
      th4.innerHTML = '<font color=blue> KALIBER </font>'; 
      trHeader.appendChild(th1);
      trHeader.appendChild(th2);
      trHeader.appendChild(th3);
      trHeader.appendChild(th4);  
      tbl.appendChild(trHeader);
        
        //create Table-Inserts, show what is in the table

      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML = results.rows[i].id;
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        td2.innerHTML = results.rows[i].hersteller;
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        td3.innerHTML = '<form method="GET" action="edit_munition.html"><input name="formstueckzahl" type="text" value="' + results.rows[i].stueckzahl + '" size="5" maxlength="4" id="' + results.rows[i].id + '">';
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');
        td4.innerHTML = results.rows[i].kaliber;
        var td5 = document.createElement('td');
        td5.innerHTML = '<input type="submit" name="form" value="update"></form>';
          
        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        tr.appendChild(td5); 
        tbl.appendChild(tr);
          
      }
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName('X')[0];
      body.appendChild(tbl);
      body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
        

    }
```

Comment: Hi, one peace of solution found. It is not possible to go over a table with a form. I must put in in one cell! Like this: >>>> 



`td3.innerHTML = '<form method="GET" action="edit_munition.html"><input name="formstueckzahl" type="text" value="' + results.rows[i].stueckzahl + '" size="5" maxlength="4" id="' + results.rows[i].id + '">' + " " + '<input type="submit" name="form" value="update"></form>';` <<<<

But, what the hell .. i need the ID in the same String after pressing the button "update"!

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
td3.innerHTML = '<form method="GET" action="edit_munition.html"><input name="formstueckzahl" type="text" value="' + results.rows[i].stueckzahl + '" size="5" maxlength="4" id="formstueckzahl"><input type="hidden" name="formid" value="' + results.rows[i].id + '">' + " " + '<input type="submit" name="form" value="update"></form>';
```